# MS Access Data type mismatch in expression only in where statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an expression that throws a data type mismatch only when in the `Where` statement.

```
Current: IIf(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)>0,
IIf(DateAdd("yyyy",CInt(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99))
,CVDate(Format(Nz([TEST_DATE],19891231),"0000-00-00")))>Now(),True,False),True)
```

As you can see, I've added an `Nz()` function to every reference and even tried to cast `CBool()` on the whole statement, but it still throws the data type mismatch.

I've pinpointed it down to this expression and *the expression works exactly as expected in `Select` statement*. When I add it to the `Where` statement looking to return only `True`, the error occurs.

What could I be missing?

Update: full query for those interested

```
SELECT Student.TECH_ID, Student.CAPP_LVL, Values.ABBR, Values.SHORT_DESC, Values.LONG_DESC, Values.GROUP_NBR, Values.NBR_YRS_VALID, Student.SEQ_NBR, Student.CAPP_LVL_SCORE, Student.TEST_DATE, IIf(Nz([Values].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)>0,IIf(DateAdd("yyyy",CInt([Values].[NBR_YRS_VALID]),CVDate(Format([TEST_DATE],"0000-00-00")))>Now(),True,False),True) AS [Current], Values.END_DATE, Student.LOAD_DATE
FROM Student INNER JOIN Values ON Student.CAPP_LVL = Values.CAPP_LVL
WHERE (((Values.ABBR)<>"MTHB") AND ((Values.END_DATE) Like "9999*"))
ORDER BY Student.TECH_ID, Student.CAPP_LVL, Student.SEQ_NBR;
```

Comment: Could you please share the full query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What data type and format is TEST_DATE? I get an error if I make it a Date/Time datatype and make the data evaluate to false, but it works if it evaluates to true. That may be why you see it working in a Select. When i make TEST_DATE a double, and use your format in the nz function (19981231) it works in all cases.

Comment: Had to bust out the data dictionary, haha. It's a char data type coming through ODBC. I tried casting 'CDbl()' on 'TEST_DATE', but didn't have any luck.

Comment: So, I would take a closer look at the data coming over. I can replicate the error by using different date formats for TEST_DATE data. I am certain your error is generated in the CVDate (updated VBA function is CDate, but they do the same thing) function, the format command somehow twists up one of the incoming dates so it can't be converted.

Comment: You're right. I isolated the CVDate() (changed to CDate(), too) and tried to use it in a where statement and got the error. Now the question is how to account for this type of problem. Ideas?

Comment: For an example, your format takes '2/1/2012' and turns it into 0004-09-40, then CDate interprets this as 4/9/1940. You don't even need the format, Access is smart enough to interpret the dates in the format they arrive in (usually).

Comment: The data is coming in as YYYYMMDD. That's why I have the format and CDate. The problem is that there used to be no validation on this field, so I could be dealing with any numeric value.

Comment: The problem is bad data, so I'm going to consider this as answered. I'm going spend some time researching how to query records that error on an expression. Thanks!

Comment: Andy, 2 suggestions for chasing this. Since this is coming over as Char, the first thing i would do is use IsNumeric to see if any data wasn't actually a number, then i would parse out the first 4 digits (Left(TEST_DATA,4) and make sure that they were between 1950 and 2012 or something.   Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I tried a few things and ended up finding out that there were a few dozen records with only the year.

Answer (score 0):

A `Where` statement doesn't look like a `Select` statement. Access is expecting a conditional expression that *it* can test for true or false.

The quick version would be take that whole statement and test it for `True`:

```
WHERE (IIf(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)>0,
IIf(DateAdd("yyyy",CInt(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99))
,CVDate(Format(Nz([TEST_DATE],19891231),"0000-00-00")))>Now(),True,False),True))
= True
```

A better solution would be to rewrite it as a few different conditional statements joined by `AND` or `OR`. I'm having trouble parsing it, so I don't think I'm going to try my hand at that.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT 
    IIf(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)>0,IIf(DateAdd("yyyy",
       CInt(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)),
       CVDate(Format(Nz([TEST_DATE],19891231),"0000-00-00")))
         >Now(),True,False),True) 
       AS [Current],
    ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL.NBR_YRS_VALID, 
    ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL.TEST_DATE
FROM ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL
WHERE (((IIf(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)>0,IIf(DateAdd("yyyy",
    CInt(Nz([ISRS_VAL_ST_CAPP_LVL].[NBR_YRS_VALID],99)),
    CVDate(Format(Nz([TEST_DATE],19891231),"0000-00-00")))
       >Now(),True,False),True))=true));
```

Both NBR_YRS_VALID and TEST_DATE are Long Integer